# Drilling holes behind existing walls/ceilings

Tags: electrical

We are remodeling a 1914 house, and want to keep damage to the walls and ceiling to a minimum.  We had to take a few walls down already, and as a result have the ability to drill new holes behind the existing wall/ceiling.

We would like to drill through 3 to 4 joists without removing the ceiling for new wiring.

The span of the 3-4 joists is about 5 feet, and we have about a foot worth of space to fit this 5 foot spade bit plus the drill.

We were thinking about using extension bars to incrementally get the spade bit across.  The only issue that I can think about is how would we keep the spade bit straight.

Would this be a "hope it works" kind of situation, or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't go this route, as it would definitely be a "hope it works" situation. For starters, I would hesitate to drill through stud bays that I didn't have access to both sides of because there is really no way to be sure you wouldn't be drilling through something important, like existing wiring for example. Second, drilling the holes is only the first challenge - fishing a wire through 4 blind holes over 5 feet is no small task. About the only way I would see this is feasible is using the bit (plus extensions) to pull the wire back through after it is drilled.

If you decide to try this, don't use a spade bit.  Five feet worth of extensions going through 100 year old seasoned floor joists is going to be practically impossible due to the amount of pressure you would have to put on the drill bit and the number of joints in the system.  I would use an auger bit instead - that way you would have the bit itself pulling the extensions taut.

Comment: Great advice to use an auger bit, and to use the bit to pull the cable.

Comment: An [alignment tool](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v1/297350055/Flex_Drill_Bit.jpg) will help you position the bit where you want it.

Comment: I was thinking about using rigid extensions, and wasn't aware of the flexible extensions.  For the more visually inclined, Google the following search to find more information about these:

licensedelectrician flex bit tips and tricks

Answer (score 0):

Use a spade bit in a drill to make the holes just big enough for wire.

Comment: I've updated the situation.